# Devise prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've been trying to redirect users(after signing in) to the previous url. However I was getting the following error:

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

So I read about it in the internet and I saw that prepending the filter in the Sessions Controller would solve the problem:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [ :new, :create ]
end
```

But I'm still getting the same error. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

**Application Controller**

```
  after_filter :store_location

  def store_location
    # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
    if (request.fullpath != "/users/sign_in" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users/sign_up" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users/password" &&
        !request.fullpath.match("/users") &&
        !request.xhr? && # don't store ajax calls
        request.format == "text/html" || request.content_type == "text/html")
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
      session[:last_request_time] = Time.now.utc.to_i
    end
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations" }, :skip => [:sessions] 
  as :user do
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need to override Devise's controllers, there's no need to use them, but if you do have that need, remove the `prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication`.

This is what I use for redirecting to the previous URL:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
after_action :store_location

# If you are requiring authentication for all your controllers you can use
#   before_action :authenticate_user! unless: :devise_controller?
# and disable particular actions in other controllers with
# require_no_authentication (except on any DeviseController)


private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || dashboard_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    new_user_session_path
  end
```

And

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :user

authenticated :user do
  root to: 'sistema/inicio#tablero_de_mando', as: :authenticated_user_root
end

root to: 'some_controller#some_action'
```

You can use `authenticate_user!` or `require_no_authentication` with before_action/before_filter on your controllers depending on weather or not you need authentication for that controller's particular action(s).

More info [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb) and [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-authentication-for-all-pages).

Answer (score 1):

The devise sessions controller already has `:require_no_authentication` prepended for `:new` and `:create`.  In my code I have a `save_last` method, much like your store_location, defined in `application_controller.rb` as a `before_action`.